# Jquery slideUp flashes problem

Tags: jquery, slideup

I have the strange flash of the content after finishing sliding up.
i have add the:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to the head of my code but then the entire page is jumping the the slidedown occur

what is my solution?

here is my code just in case:

```
$("#contentbottom").slideUp(500, function() {
var dataString = 'type='+t;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: link,
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#contentbottom").empty().append(msg);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('error: unable to load the additonal info');
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        $("#contentbottom").slideDown(500);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Can you describe "jumping" a bit more?  Is it because the content is growing overall, or flickering...what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

My guess, without seeing any of your markup, is that `$("#contentbottom").empty().append(msg);` is populated with the AJAX response causing your browser to flash/scroll down to the new content, then back up to the top.

If you don't have any CSS styles to hide the `#contentbottom` element when it's empty, that might be a part problem. Yu could just do `$('#contentbottom').hide()` in your slideUp handler before you AJAX call, then `$("#contentbottom").empty().append(msg).show()` in the success handler...